# Are there any concerns with sending and storing 3rd party cookies?

Tags: http, cookies

I have a userscript for an browser game that I use to send users cookies to my webserver. I then use those cookies to pull player specific data and compile it into reports for those players.

The game, and my website use HTTPS. I am storing the cookies in an encrypted database table and then using them to perform the data-pulls server-side.

What sort of security concerns arise from this sort of setup, and what should I do to mitigate them? Is the premises very insecure to start?

Answer (score 2):

InfoSec is always a balance between risk, cost, and convenience.  In your case we're talking about a game that perhaps is not well known, so it is not a high value target.  If there is literally nothing worth hacking, there is nothing worth protecting.

Also, InfoSec tends to focus on [threat modeling](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/threat-modeling) specific [attack vectors](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/attack-vector).  You may not have to do anything if there are no attacks that would cause you grief, e.g. if the only attacks that would work are ones that don't affect anything important to your operations.  So you should try to list these.  What sorts of things are you worried a hacker could accomplish?  For example, is it a big deal if someone can alter their own scores and reports?  Is it a big deal if they could see someone else's scores?  If they could modify them?  Etc.

That being said, I can introduce you to a couple general practices that certainly wouldn't hurt anything if you did them:

If you are actually storing data in the cookies (as opposed to an identifier which can be used to obtain data) then the cookies can be modified by any user who is in control of the machine on which the cookie is stored.  Of course, they can only modify their own cookies.  But if this is still a concern, you can make your cookies a bit tamper-resistant through various means: you could encrypt the cookie (probably using private key symmetric encryption like [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)), or you could sign the cookie with a [Machine Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

If you are not storing data, only an ID, and you use the ID to get data from the database, there are three suggestions I'd make.  First, make the identifier random, not sequential, so that nobody can guess others' IDs just by adding 1 to their own ID.  Second, generate the identifier with sufficient entropy (say, 64 bits) so that it is difficult to find IDs using a brute force search.  Third, tie the identifier to a user (e.g. add a UserID column to the database table) and check to make sure it matches the current authenticated user before you pull any data.

If you are worried about physical security of the endpoint-- e.g. a user playing your game in a coffee shop, who leaves the computer without clearing his cookies-- then I suggest that your cookie be provided with an expiration, or that it be a [session cookie](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/session_cookie.html) which is deleted when the user closes the browser.  Re-issue the cookie when the user signs on using his user name and password.

If you are worried that a hacker could use the cookie to inject malicious code into your application, use the cookie only to store an identifier in a known format, and validate the format of the cookie when it is submitted to your server.

Comment: Hey John, I do not own the game. I am writing a script that other uses use, which collects their information and sends it to a 3rd party (my) webserver. I then use their cookies to run requests against the games servers to collect data. What I am wondering, is if I can with confidence say there isn't a significant risk for the users caused by me doing this. If there is, what would the most significant risks and their sources be?